# How to extract msi file using multiple instances - JAVA?

Tags: java, processbuilder, windows-installer

I tried below command and its working perfectly,

```
msiexec /a source.msi  /qb TARGETDIR=destination
```

But i could not able to do this process in parallel.(Getting another installation is in progress). So how do i make it or is there any other way i can extract msi files using java?

Comment: Can the `Windows Installer` run multiple instances of itself ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? It is a simple restriction on the Windows Installer.

Comment: Yah, But can we create a multiple instances in java for the windows installer and do that, is there a way?

Comment: am writing utility to extract msi file using java standalone so..is there any API which supports this impl?

Comment: That indeed depends on the limits of Windows Installer, like @Seelenvirtuose said. If it supports multiple instances to be running in parallel, then simply create two threads, that would be sufficient. Otherwise, if Windows Installer restricts running multiple instances, there's no way to prevent that.

Comment: Yep.. Its restricted.. Thanks a lot @Seelenvirtuose and thanks too MC Emperor

Comment: Trying to run multiple instances of msiexec will lead you to _MSI Error 1618: 'Another installation is already in progress'_

Comment: Yah getting same error, But wanted to extract the MSI files using java standalone. couldn't able to find any API supports that!!

Comment: So is there any java api which does MSI extraction???

Comment: Can anyone please tell me ,how do i extract the MSI file without msiexec? or is there any java API available to do that? (Not a singleton way)